# Triangular part of a table

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I would like to access the lower triangular part of a (square) table with cell elements. I tried the `tril` function, but it doesn't work for input arguments of type 'cell'. Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: What is "a table of cell elements"? Is it a 2D cell array? And what should be the result format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
c = {1, [2 3], 4; [5 6 7], [8 9], 10; 11, 12, [13 14]}; %// example 3x3 cell array
mask = tril(true(size(c,1), size(c,2))); %// creat mask
result = c(mask); %// index cell array with mask
```

This produces a column cell array with the selected cells in column-major order:

```
result{1} =
     1
result{2} =
     5     6     7
result{3} =
    11
result{4} =
     8     9
result{5} =
    12
result{6} =
    13    14
```